# How to match column with similar but different formats from 2 MySQL tables to join them into one MySQL table?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I wanna know how to join 2 tables into one based on a column named 'Chamber_ID', however, with 2 different formats. Table A has the column with the format: SG_QRA_SGHAST_0001, 0002, etc. and Table B has the same column with format like: SGHAST.0001, 0002, etc. Does anyone know how to start this complicated task and which language should I use (Python perhaps?)? Thank you!

Comment: Can the "SGHAST" part be different? or only the numbers at the end are changing?

Comment: for now im matching one by one first so sghast.0001 is = sg_qra_sghast_0001 and so on i wanna try that first

Answer (score 0):

In case the letters are static and the only thing that changes are the numbers,
you can take a substring of the last 4 characters, which will leave you with the numbers only (with leading zeros), and then you can compare them ('0001' = '0001')

for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM A, B
WHERE SUBSTRING(A.Chamber_ID,-4,4) = SUBSTRING(B.Chamber_ID,-4,4)
```

If you prefer inner join Syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON SUBSTRING(A.Chamber_ID,-4,4) = SUBSTRING(B.Chamber_ID,-4,4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But i just realised the SG_QRA_SGHAST_0001 has 2 extra characters at the back SG_QRA_SGHAST_0001Z1, 0001Z2, ..., 00001Z6 in Table A. So i want to have 6 rows of SGHAST.0001 (like in Table B) but containing the Z1 to Z6 (but this one only seen in Table A). Do u know how to do so? thank u so much once agn!

Comment: you can still use the same answer above, with some changes. on table A use SUBSTRING(A.Chamber_ID,-6,4)  
This will give you for each Z1 to Z6 record the same record in the B table (will duplicate B record values for each matching A record)

Comment: i tried this bc of the substring condition but i got 0 row returned :" and idk why.

Comment: Some examples of actual data can help understand what are you trying to achieve and why it's not working

Comment: I figured it out but what about having 2 or more conditions/criteria that indicate they are the same using substring method? (like having 2 or 3 substrings that are the same as the conditions)